# MySQL select older rows than x days, group by and order by and limit

Tags: php, mysql, date, group-by, sql-order-by

I made a really ugly SQL table long time ago. But now I need to use the data from it. 
The table looks like this:
`id => 1`
`video_id => gds1513sfsd51`
`user_ip => 244.154.16..`
`datum => 2011-01-11 10:10:10`
`referer => http://something.com`
`user_id => 1`

I whould like to get those rows are older than 30 days, but I would like to `group` them by `video_id` and `order` by `id` desc

So, these are the rows

```
id          video_id            ip               datum                user_id
527557  152547560451c58ca74e2e8 162.217.250.110 2013-11-18 21:53:10     1
527556  152547560451c58ca74e2e8 162.217.250.110 2013-11-18 21:53:07     1
527369  152547560451c58ca74e2e8 162.217.250.110 2013-11-18 21:37:03     1
515760  152547560451c58ca74e2e8 108.178.60.2    2013-11-15 02:33:45     1
515763  252547560451c58ca74e2e9 108.178.60.2    2013-10-15 02:33:45     2
515764  252547560451c58ca74e2e9 108.178.60.5    2013-10-14 02:33:45     2
```

I would like to get only the row with id `515763` , because that is older than one month and there is no newer with that `video_id` .

I have tried to make something like this one:

```
    $format = 'Y-m-j G:i:s'; 
    $date = date ( $format ); 
    // - 1 month from today 
   $datum = date ( $format, strtotime ( '-1 month' . $date ) );

$query = 'SELECT * FROM video_megtekintes WHERE datum <= "'.$datum.'" group by video_id order by id desc LIMIT 100';

print($query.'<hr>');
$le = mysql_query($query);

while($i = mysql_fetch_assoc($le)){
print($i["video_id"].' - '.$i["datum"].'');
$ok = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM video_megtekintes WHERE video_id="'.$i["video_id"].'" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'));
print(' - <b>'.$ok["datum"].'</b><br>');
//
```

But the output is something like this now:
(video_id | datum | and the latest rows' datum with the same video_id)

```
video_id                   datum               from_a_new_query_it_shows_me_there_is_newer
1000657739521a10654224f - 2013-08-25 19:15:26 - 2013-12-05 05:56:20
100155265051bde3b822f84 - 2013-06-18 20:59:31 - 2013-11-04 23:48:06
10024035651dc34f02b5d4 - 2013-07-14 10:10:52 - 2013-10-04 19:57:06
```

I don't want to see the first row, because it has two dates.. That video_id is with a newer date than one month. Can you help me a bit, please?

This is the query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM video_megtekintes WHERE datum <= "'.$datum.'" group by video_id order by id desc LIMIT 100';
```

Comment: It's unclear (to me at least), what the query is that produces the result set shown. Also it looks like if you don't want to see that first row, then you also don't want to see the other 2, correct?

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY datum DESC` instead of `ORDER BY id`?

Comment: datum  > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()

Comment: If that is the query that produces that output, then why does the output contain 2 date fields when the table you're selecting from only has 1 date column?

Comment: This part `$datum = date ( $format, strtotime ( '-1 month' . $date ) );` is wrong, that should be a comma not a period: `strtotime ( '-1 month', $date )`

Comment: Now a repaired the decsription. :-) Sorry. Actually it gets that row is older than one month. But it get that if it has a newer date with the same video_id.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the most recent video_id (i.e., only 1 row) for records that are older than 1 month.  Also the video_id does not have any records within the last month.

```
SELECT *
FROM video_megtekintes
JOIN (
   SELECT video_megtekintes.video_id AS video_id, MAX(video_megtekintes.datum) as maxdate
   FROM video_megtekintes 
   LEFT JOIN video_megtekintes AS newer_t
     ON newer_t.video_id = video_megtekintes.video_id
       AND newer_t.datum > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
   WHERE video_megtekintes.datum <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      AND newer_t.video_id IS NULL
   GROUP BY video_id) AS t1
  ON video_megtekintes.datum = t1.maxdate
    AND video_megtekintes.video_id = t1.video_id
```

Comment: You undertsood what I whould like to do. The most recent video_id older than one month. :-) But this gives me the same result. (I modified t1.video.id to t1.video_id... But the same result is given to me. )

Comment: @user2301881 - This change eliminates video_id that have an entry within the last month also.

Comment: What does ambiguous means? `Column 'datum' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @user2301881 - It means the MySQL does not know which 'datum' to use. to solve it put the table alias and a period (.) before the column name. I changed the query above to reflect the change (It was in the MAX() function)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it. :-) I thing it should work, but only gives me 500 error, even I set the limit to 1... So can't get the first row even. :-s (My english is a bit poor and I couldn't translate that word :-) )

Comment: Isn't it an "unclosed" circle? You now: while($x < 1){ print('apple'); }